# webview movie with iframe

Tags: java, iframe, webview, javafx

I made a VBOX with a Webview and a Label
The Label shows a little text; but the WebView doesn't show a video.
So I read a xml file correctly and I get this String:

```
<iframe width="480" height="270" src="//v.traileraddict.com/99694" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

So what I do in my code is the following:

```
    //filmtrailer = WebView and webviewstring = String above    
    filmtrailer.getEngine().load(webviewstring);
```

But this doesn't give me the trailer.

Comment: `WebView` doesn't support any plugins, which is how a typical web browser displays a video. You can use a JavaFX [`MediaView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/media-tutorial/overview.htm#JFXMD101) to view video (if it is in a supported format).

Comment: Do you have any idea how to make a mediaplayer of the iframe string?

Comment: As far as I can tell the only format that website is providing is Shockwave Flash, so no. (However there are other SO users who have far more knowledge than I have of video format and encoding, and I may be wrong.)

Comment: I found a way to play the movie in a webview, I will post the answer later, but still thanks for your time @James_D

Comment: Ah, interesting; it does work in web view; I guess web view supports HTML5 video. It would be interesting to know the details of how that works.

Comment: the only thing I had to do was replace // by http:// after src: